# Disable alert when manually deleting a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way in VBA to disable the alert that pops up when MANUALLY deleting a sheet (right click sheet and delete)? I have seen `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, however this seems to only work for me when deleting a sheet using VBA (`Sheets("Sheet1").delete`). I am trying to disable the alert for the whole workbook when you manually right click on a sheet and click delete. Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of a way to do that **without** using VBA? I think this question belongs to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed, I do not know of a way to do it without VBA, however it would not be very useful to me if it were not in VBA as it needs to be toggled on and off automatically. Thanks for the suggestion to post on Super User, I will try there.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for the [same scenario](https://superuser.com/questions/1318589/disable-alert-when-manually-deleting-a-sheet):

> ...eliminate the need to confirm deleting a sheet when presenting the
>   workbook in meetings. While going through the sheets I often double
>   click on pivot tables to view detail, and I would like to eliminate
>   the pop-up alert when I delete the generated sheet...

If new sheets are generated only when double-clicking a pivot table, this might be a suitable solution

Placed in `ThisWorkbook`, the code bellow will delete any new sheets, when selecting a different sheet

---

```
Option Explicit

'Place this code in ThisWorkbook module

'Expects that all new sheets are generated by double-clicking a pivot table

Private pivotWs As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set pivotWs = Sh
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Not pivotWs Is Nothing Then
        If Sh.Name = pivotWs.Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            pivotWs.Delete
            Set pivotWs = Nothing
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @paul bica, this is definitely a useful method to deal with the issue, great idea!